# Converting nvarchar to int, converting phone with symbols with only numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, integer, nvarchar

I am trying to convert phone number from the column 'phone' from the table 'Clients'. I have tried the following syntaxes, but I still get error messages -

```
1. SELECT CAST(phone as int)
   FROM Clients
```

Error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '030-3456789' to data type int

```
2. SELECT CONVERT(int, phone)
   FROM Clients
```

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '030-3456789' to data type int.

```
3. SELECT CAST(phone AS BIGINT)
   FROM Clients
   WHERE ISNUMERIC(phone) = 1
```

The query doesn't return error but there is no result, the column is empty.

Comment: What database do you use ? Oracle, SQLServer... ?

Comment: Why do you want to convert a phonenumber to an int? You'll loose leading zero's, invalidating the phonenumber. A phonenumber is, despite its name, not a number

Comment: Obviously you can't convert non-numeric digits to an integer so you'll need to remove those first. How you do that depends on your specific RDBMS which you have (not yet) tagged.

Comment: I am using SQLServer. I want to loose the parentheses and the hyphen and instead of (5) 789-0123 to receive only 57890123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks (from your example syntax) like you might be using SQL Server.

If that's the case and it's 2017+ you can do the following which copes with any combination of non-numeric values.

Based on your comments the following should work

```
select Try_Convert(bigint, Replace(Translate('(5) 789-0123','()-','   '),' ',''))
```

> Result: 57890123

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or earlier you have to nest multiple replacements:

```
select Try_Convert(bigint, Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace('(5) 789-0123)','-',''),'(',''),')',''),' ',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because at least some of your records cannot be covert to numeric by default, as the indicated one **030-3456789**
You basically need to replace/eliminate the dash in between:

```
SELECT cast(replace('12-3', '-', '') as int)
```

Comment: and if there's more than one character that need to be replaced, I recommend REGEXP